# Intel Broadwell Power Consumption and Clock Speed

Tags: cpu, power, battery-life

I'm configuring a new MacBook Pro 15″ 2015 and wanted to know if the processor speed affects the battery life (power consumption) assuming that the work load is identical?

```
2.5GHz Quad-core Intel Core i7, Turbo Boost up to 3.7GHz
2.8GHz Quad-core Intel Core i7, Turbo Boost up to 4.0GHz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, "[Power consumption is about linear with frequency.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34766/how-does-power-consumption-vary-with-the-processor-frequency-in-a-typical-comput)"

If I'm understanding that correctly, it would mean that the slower processor could consume less power at low intensity workloads. But also shown on that page is that the higher the workload, the less efficiency it has (it's not truly linear, in other words). So that would mean that the lower speed processor could be expected to be more energy efficient at light tasks, but it may use more power at 3.4 Ghz, for instance, than the more powerful processor, which would be running more efficiently at that speed.